# Linking a specific shared object

Tags: cmake, linker, shared-libraries

I'm using cmake, and I was trying to find how to link to a specific shared object. For example, libva-wayland has 2 shared objects `libva-wayland.so` and `libva-wayland.so.1`. In this instance, specifying the library automatically creates a dependency on the latter.

Even when explicitly specifying the file in `CMakeLists.txt` as such, `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-x11.so...`, it still links to `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-x11.so.1`.

I am verifying the specific so that my binary is linked against using `ldd`

I realize that we want to keep links specified like this because you want to make sure it is using the right version, but I want to deploy on a different system that using version 2.x.x of libva, and the dependency on 1.x.x causes it not to work on that system.

Is this achievable? I'm guessing that I might have to make some changes to ldconfig?

Thanks

Comment: Try using absolute path for the library.

Comment: @arrowd I had tried using the absolute path, but somehow, it still links to the undesired symlink.

Comment: On your "now deleted" [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040505/javascript-wait-for-all-promises-to-finish), the only way to answer whether there's a smarter, more recommended way to do it is in the context of your code. There is NO generic answer for a question like that.  It looks like you've been around here enough to know that generic, theoretical questions just don't work very well here. They require dozens of pages to cover all the possible permutations.  It works a lot better to show your code, get an answer and then ask follow-on comments about other situations if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to deploy on a different system that using version 2.x.x of libva, and the dependency on 1.x.x causes it not to work on that system.

This is done *by design*.

It is *desired* that your program linked against `1.x` version of the library does not start on a `2.x` system, because these libraries have different `ABI`. If this program was allowed to run, it would likely crash.

Read about external library versioning [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1386/6m7qcoblb/index.html).

TL;DR: If you want your program to run on a `2.x`-based system, you *must* build it against headers and libraries that are `2.x` themselves. There is *no way* to build a single executable that will work on both `1.x` and `2.x`.